# PHP will not execute properly and only displays as text

Tags: php

My entire PHP page only displays as text and no PHP code is executed. It's weird because when I test it using `<? phpinfo(); ?>` in a test.php file, I get a successful test and it works on my Apache server. However when I attempt to do anything else. It only shows as text.

Edit: Here is the link to the code. I couldn't figure out how to post it here. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UdWq8Gmc)

```
<?php
  // create short variable names
  $tireqty = $_POST['tireqty'];
  $oilqty = $_POST['oilqty'];
  $sparkqty = $_POST['sparkqty'];
  $find = $_POST['find'];
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bob's Auto Parts - Order Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bob's Auto Parts</h1>
<h2>Order Results</h2>
<?php

    echo "<p>Order processed at ".date('H:i, jS F Y')."</p>";

    echo "<p>Your order is as follows: </p>";

    $totalqty = 0;
    $totalqty = $tireqty + $oilqty + $sparkqty;
    echo "Items ordered: ".$totalqty."<br />";


    if ($totalqty == 0) {

      echo "You did not order anything on the previous page!<br />";

    } else {

      if ($tireqty > 0) {
        echo $tireqty." tires<br />";
      }

      if ($oilqty > 0) {
        echo $oilqty." bottles of oil<br />";
      }

      if ($sparkqty > 0) {
        echo $sparkqty." spark plugs<br />";
      }
    }


    $totalamount = 0.00;

    define('TIREPRICE', 100);
    define('OILPRICE', 10);
    define('SPARKPRICE', 4);

    $totalamount = $tireqty * TIREPRICE
                 + $oilqty * OILPRICE
                 + $sparkqty * SPARKPRICE;

    echo "Subtotal: $".number_format($totalamount,2)."<br />";

    $taxrate = 0.10;  // local sales tax is 10%
    $totalamount = $totalamount * (1 + $taxrate);
    echo "Total including tax: $".number_format($totalamount,2)."<br />";

    if($find == "a") {
      echo "<p>Regular customer.</p>";
    } elseif($find == "b") {
      echo "<p>Customer referred by TV advert.</p>";
    } elseif($find == "c") {
      echo "<p>Customer referred by phone directory.</p>";
    } elseif($find == "d") {
      echo "<p>Customer referred by word of mouth.</p>";
    } else {
      echo "<p>We do not know how this customer found us.</p>";
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you trying to view the file?

Comment: server? local? remote? details please.

Comment: Well it's nothing to do with the code. The code I have is from a book that I'm using to learn PHP so it is 100% correct. I just don't know how to make it work without appearing as text.

Comment: From book so "100% correct" LOL. No, really many books are full of errors. So as asked befog, show us the code.

Comment: I have an Apache server running on my Windows computer. I'm using it to try and learn PHP through a book. To view files I have to type in localhost. So like I said, a test is working just fine but when I try to implement the files from the book they don't work and they are correct.

Comment: I get that books are full of errors but I've looked through this one furiously, tried examples from other chapters, tried simple PHP but to no avail with any of them except for a simple test for phpinfo that does work.

Comment: code code code, how hard is it to copy and paste. do you expect we have psychic powers?

Comment: Well I attempted to copy and paste but this is my first attempt at posting here and I seem to be having trouble getting PHP to show up properly when trying to post.

Comment: paste the code, then select it and click the button `{}` from the top of the edit box, it says `code sample`. It will insert 4 spaces in front of each line of code, and it will display properly.

Comment: bad book, where's the error handling? where's the checking he POST exists. add *error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');* to the top of the file after *<?php*

Comment: Well those chapters haven't been covered yet. I'm literally in the first chapter of the book. It worked fine as of yesterday and I was moving right along but this today has just completely stopped me dead in my tracks because I can't make any progress without the PHP being executed like it was yesterday.

Comment: did you turn the server on yesterday, but not turn it on today?

Comment: what's the url you're typing in your browser?

Comment: localhost/orderform.html    When you submit the stuff on that page it goes to localhost/processorder.php

Comment: ahhhhaaaaaa .html will not be parsed as php by default. easy option - change file name (orederform.php), or configure server to server html via php.

Comment: This comment was a confusion, or I am confused. The PHP file we're talking about here is processorder.php. orderform.html contains a form, and this code doesn't. So I guess it's processorder.php.

Comment: Okay the weirdest part just happened because it just now started working again. I changed nothing. I restarted nothing. I just typed in the address again to relook at the issue and now it's working.

Comment: hurm - dubious, but ok. best of luck with the rest of the book :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do appreciate you trying to help more than you know. I'm glad this community seems to be very well put together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am willing to bet 10$ that `test.php` uses `<?php`, and the changed code uses `<?`, while the server does not understand it as an opening tag since `short_open_tags` is off in php.ini.

A lot of books use `<?` for open tags, while most servers only support the long version (`<?php`). If that's the case, then changing all the simple `<?` to `<?php` will do the trick.

PHP code is only exposed in 1 case: When PHP interpreter does not identify it as PHP code. That can be caused by only 2 problems:

- Wrong configuration of Apache (or other http server) which doesn't handle php files at all.
- Wrong open tags in PHP files, so PHP doesn't know when code begins.

If the file is a *.php, if Apache is turned on serving *.php files through PHP interpreter, if standard open tags are used or PHP is configured to use other types of used tags, and if you're accessing this PHP file through the browser, in no circumstances would PHP expose this code.

Comment: Saw this recently on a website which was exposing PHP code, played with it for a while. Had fun.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I wish that were the case, all of it uses <code><?php</code>

Comment: So what would be the cause for a php file not to work today if it worked yesterday on the exact same server with no changes?

Comment: well, hell. All is as it should from the code perspective. Files are .PHP, and if you say that yesterday they worked, and now they don't, then something happened either to PHP or to Apache. I suggest you reconfigure them or something. There is nothing wrong with your code or its placement.